# Problems after Updating USB Drivers (BSOD and more)

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, bsod, usb-c

I updated all drivers of my pc. After updating them an USB Cable(for samsung) doesn't work. It used to work perfectly fine before updating. This cable isn't an original one, so I tried an original cable which came with the phone. It worked. I dont really wanna use this original cable because it's damanged, and I can't do a system restore for some reason(it says "Windows cannot find /path/rstrui.exe" even tho its there, I scaned the whole pc with Avast and no viruses were found). Before updating drivers the non-original cable worked fine(it transferred files), but now it doesn't even show up phone files in PC. Sometimes when I plug in an usb devise in my pc a BSOD occurs, but rarely. How can I fix this issue? I used Driver Easy program to update my drivers. Then I downloaded the latest drivers from the official Intel page and installed them manually but it still doesn't work

Comment: I never use a driver update program. Use Windows system restore point to get it working again.>>>>https://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/windows-7/fix-windows-7-with-a-system-restore-point/

Comment: That's the perfect reason to never use those snake oil driver update programs. They are nothing but trouble. Once you've managed to get back to your restore point, throw that app out.

Comment: @Moab I mentonied in the question that I can't use windows system restore, I don't know why. And I updated the drivers like 3 months ago.

Comment: If you did it 3 months ago, why do you think that is the cause of the issue now? …and why was that important detail not in your question? It reads as if one was directly prior to the other.

Comment: Find rstrui.exe and double click it to launch, does this work?

Comment: @Moab I tried but it doesnt work.

Comment: any errors? if so what?

Comment: @Tetsujin I had the issue right after updating drivers, I just asked now

Comment: @Moab  the error is : "Windows cannot find 'C:\Windows\system32\rstrui.exe'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.". rstrui.exe is there, but when you open it in system32 it gives the same problem

Comment: even when you launch it from the system32 folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107547/discussion-between-ador007-and-moab).